# firebase signout take some time to perform action

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am building react native app in which authenticating process is based on firebase
the issue which i am facing right now is, when i try to sign out from firebase,

**Here is a code:**

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    console.log('STEP 1: Signed Out');
    realm.write(() => {       
           realm.create('userAuthentication', {id:1, userid: '',   username: '', password: ''}, true);
            });

            userAuth = realm.objects('userAuthentication');
            console.log( "STEP 2:" + JSON.stringify(userAuth) );
            this.goHomeRedirect();

        }, function(error) {
          console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
        }); 

userAuth = realm.objects('userAuthentication');
console.log( "STEP 3 :" + JSON.stringify(userAuth) );
```

**It give Output:**

STEP 1

STEP 3

STEP 2

If anybody has faced this kind of issue with firebase? kindly help me out on this issue.

Comment: Sign-out (like most operations with cloud services on the modern web) happens asynchronously. So this is the expected behavior. What is the problem?

Comment: it give me signin or signout flag after second click